# Call Web-service every 30 seconds from current latitude and longitude in background

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps, background-service

- I can able to fetch current lat-long in background
- I am able to call web-service normally
- But when it comes to run web-service in background i am totally unknown to that
- I need to call web-service every 30 seconds in background from current lat-long.
- Suggestions or demo are heartly welcom

Comment: probably: http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583426/getting-latitude-and-longitude-using-gps-every-10-minute-in-background-android?rq=1

Comment: can u plz share a demo

Comment: i am able to get lat-long in background,but unable to do anything with service

Comment: @RC,i have done same thing for lat-long as u mention in comment,but what abt web-service