# Can I tracking gps latitude and longitude by a service that always run in background?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location, android-broadcastreceiver, android-gps

I want to get latitude and longitude by a service that do in background and when the app is not run.
Is there someone who guides me with an example ?
The most important thing is that when the program is completely closed, the service will work correctly and show the latitude and longitude.
My request is very similar to the following link.

[getting latitude and longitude using gps every 10 minute in background android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583426/getting-latitude-and-longitude-using-gps-every-10-minute-in-background-android)

None of the apps I was looking for in the background or when the program was closed was not properly executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code to get location updates periodically in background service**

Change LOCATION_INTERVAL &

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyLocationService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    /*
    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };
    */

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        initializeLocationManager();

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,
                    LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]
            );
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        /*try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]
            );
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listener, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager - LOCATION_INTERVAL: "+ LOCATION_INTERVAL + " LOCATION_DISTANCE: " + LOCATION_DISTANCE);
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a toast to the right place to show lat and lon when app is not run ? when the app is run every thing is ok but when app close my service stoped.

Comment: On which android version you are running this code?